# data structure for making matrix in julia

Tags: data-structures, parallel-processing, julia

I think `append!`is more efficient than `vcat` in both sequential and parallel way and also it's more efficient than `push!` in sequential too. Is there something like `push` or `appened` that work like `hcat`? because they work like `vcat` and I'm looking for something that it's like `hcat` but more efficient. I have a lot of n*1 vectors and I want to make a matrix by something more efficient than `hcat`.

Comment: I can see why you might think this is possible, since matrices are stored in column major order (in Julia). To my knowledge, nothing like this has been implemented. This is probably because you could get the same effect, and with greater flexibility, by using a `Vector{Vector{T}}` for storage, and `push!` new vectors to the outer vector.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand would you please give an example?

Comment: There's a quick and efficient solution if you use `VectorOfArray` from RecursiveArrayTools.jl. First of all, `VectorOfArray` is a lazy matrix, so it'll never allocate the matrix. It indexes like a matrix, so in many cases this is all that's needed. But if you made a `typeof(A) <: Vector{Vector{T}}`, you can `convert(Array,VectorOfArray(A))` and that'll use Cartesians and all of that jazz, doing only one matrix allocation. That's an easy way to take @ColinTBowers's answer and efficiently get a matrix at least.

Comment: How many is "a lot"? If it's within the limits of your memory, then simply preallocate the matrix and assign each vector by its column index (in parallel or otherwise).

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas nice shameless plug back there btw, ahahah :p

Comment: Well it solves the problem well. "then simply preallocate the matrix and assign each vector by its column index" is actually much slower. It surprised me at first, but using a lazy type and using the fallback convert is much faster because of the magic of Cartesians. So I mentioned it because it's faster and easier to do than rolling your own here.

Comment: where can I find some tutorial about lazy type for learning to how to use it?

Comment: If all the vectors are n*1 vectors, you can simply use `push!` and `append!` to create a long vector and then `reshape` the long vector into an `n*m` matrix. This takes minimal allocations and uses the optimized vector operations. The other solutions suggested are also good. But, generally, you should really get your program working before *measuring*, finding, and fixing the performance problems.